# Using jQuery hide in Rails view

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have been using Rails for some time, so I am familiar with the general structure of Rails and its Views and their Helpers such as link_to, etc.  But I am new to jQuery and am trying to start using it inside the Views for Rails.  I am trying to use the tutorial on the following page to see how to add a link to side a field on the resulting view's html page but when I use the hide example with one of the elements on my view for my existing model nothing happens, meaning no hide link appears on the view and I do not see the related jQuery javascript in the application.js file as the tutorial on following page says I should:

https://www.engineyard.com/blog/using-jquery-with-rails-how-to

please see following code block on page above:
I used following code as example for adding hide class and the data: {'js-hide-link' => true } to my existing view.  i checked the resulting view on development environment, and the data-js-hide-link = true does show up but does not see to do anything.

```
<ul>
  <% @tutorials.each do |tutorial| %>
    <li><%= tutorial.title %> <%= link_to "Hide", "", class: 'hide', data: {'js-hide-link' => true} %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

the tutorial says this should add following link to my view, but I do not see it when I check:

```
<a data-js-hide-link="true" href="">Hide</a>
```

also, as i mentioned in question above, the tutorial says I should see following as a result in my application.js file, but I do not see anything at all.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-js-hide-link]').click(function(event){
    alert('You clicked the Hide link');
    event.preventDefault(); 
  });
}
```

If you can give me a suggestion of what I should check, I would greatly appreciate it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should check `class: 'hide'`. Try to remove them and refresh page.